# JPA 2.0 : Embedded inherited abstract Class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate and I have the following classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_SLIP")
public class OrderSlip {
    @EmbeddedId
    OrderNumber orderNumber;

    @Embedded
    OrderDetails orderDetails;
}

@Embeddable
public abstract class OrderDetail implements Serializable {

    String commonOrderDetailField;
}    

@Embeddable
public class BuyOrderDetail extends OrderDetail implements Serializable {

    String field1;
    String field2;
}        

@Embeddable
public class SellOrderDetail extends OrderDetail implements Serializable {

    String field3;
    String field4;
}
```

When I run the program, the fields in the OrderDetail class are embedded in the ORDER_SLIP table. The fields of the two subclasses of OrderDetail (BuyOrderDetail and SellOrderDetail) are not as I logically expect them to be.

Is this possible at all with JPA / Hibernate?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You should take a look at
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#inheritance

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. You please describe the contents of link rather than simply including a link as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement inheritance between `@Embeddable` classes. You just have to annotate the parent class with `@MappedSuperclass` too.

So, e.g.:

```
@Embeddable
@MappedSuperclass
public class Parent {
    @Basic
    private String parentProperty;

    // ... getters/setters
}

@Embeddable
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Basic
    private String childProperty;

    // ... getters/setters
}
```

This way Hibernate (tested with 5.x) will map both `parentProperty` and `childProperty` correctly in the `Child` class.

In your example you can take advantage of the inheritance only if you use one of your subtypes in the OrderSlip class (not the parent type).

Comment: OrderSlip has OrderDetail. How to know concrete class? It looks like that OrderSlip can't make the instance of OrderDetail appropriately